# Постоянная отправка сообщений при удержании кнопки

Tags: android

Есть система клиент-сервер. Клиент на андроиде, сервер на делфях. Всё в принципе работает, нажимаешь на button, сообщение считывается с edit и отправляется. Вопрос в следующем, как сделать так, чтобы сообщение отправлялось не один раз, а постоянно, пока я не отпущу клавишу.
Вот код отправки сообщения:

```
public void onClick3(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // отправляем сообщения, снова и снова
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // прекращаем отправку сообщений
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: не получаетсяу меня что-то, вылетает, хотяя наверно просто по неопытности пишу не правильно.

Comment: Покажите стектрейс возникающего исключения.

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется что событие ACTION_DOWN и ACTION_UP срабатывают по разу. И, комментарий, "// отправляем сообщения, снова и снова", надо рассматривать как "// Взводим флаг для отправки сообщений". И, в отдельной треде, запускаем в цикле отправку сообщений, если этот флаг установлен.

Comment: Я новичок, в этом деле, делаю задание, по учёбе, никак не получается это реализовать. Ели я пришлю вам все исходники того что уже работает, вы сможете реализовать на одной кнопке, для примера, данную систему отправки сообщений, чтобы я разобрался уже в дальнейшем?

Comment: @Stenlav, вы лучше пробуйте сами разобраться, а если с чем-то конкретным возникнут затруднения — задавайте вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Ловить надо оба события нажатия и отпускания.

1. По событию `ACTION_DOWN` начать асинхронный цикл (тред) отправки сообщений
2. Далее по `ACTION_UP` останавливать цикл отправки сообщений, через остановку треда отправляющего сообщения

Answer (score -1):

А если отправлять сообщение в событие MouseDown ?

Comment: откуда, простите, в Андроиде такое событие???

Comment: Вообще есть себе совершенно спокойно. И мышку можно подключить не парясь, на уровне ядра. Возьмите переходник с микро юсб на юсб маму, воткните туда мышь и наслаждайтесь её у себя на телефоне :-)

Comment: @Чад , Да что вы говорите?? А то я не знаю, что такое "OTG". Но событие MouseDown, как бы вы не старались, вы не вызовете ни каким образом. (Можно, конечно переписать из исходников Android, добавить такое событие, но оно не начнет работать на всех Андроид дивайсах от этого)

Comment: @metalurgus, правда Ваша :-) Я имел в виду что событие от мыши отдельно отловить можно совершенно спокойно. Но оно не вынесено отдельно, а может быть распознано как уточнение. А что такое "OTG" ? :-)